# Query.swap Backwards compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, hebrew

I'm trying to use a datepicker known as [flexcal](http://github.bililite.com/flexcal) on my site. It is important for me to use it accurately, to allow selection from a Jewish calendar. My site is based on jQuery v3.3.1, but flexcal was designed for jQuery v2.1.3. I thought it shouldn't cause any problems, but I came across the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.swap is not a function

After searching, I found [here](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/) that this is a method that was intended to be private and was never documented, Anyway at the moment I'm having trouble embedding a widget on my site. Reviewing the source code of the widget reveals that the use of the method looks like this:

```js
return $.swap(
            parent,
            {display:'inline-block'}, // make it visible but shrink to contents
            swapper.bind(this, elem, parent.parentNode)         
        );
```

Does anyone know what the purpose of the method is, does it have a parallel alternative, or some other troubleshooting advice?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2058 tracks removal of public access to jQuery.swap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source of `jQuery.swap` (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.4.1/src/css/var/swap.js), you'll see that all it does is temporarily change some CSS attributes of the first argument (`parent`, in your case), run a calculation, and the restore the original attribute values.  You can implement that yourself.  It's particularly easy in your case, since the only CSS attribute we're temporarily changing is `display`:

```
var old_display = parent.style['display'];
parent.style['display'] = 'inline-block';
var ret = swapper.bind(this, elem, parent.parentNode).apply(parent, []);
parent.style['display'] = old_display;
return ret;
```